# Backdoor file with custom payload

Tags: social-engineering, metasploit

Is there a way in metasploit to add a custom exe/script as payload to a file (exe/pdf/doxc)?

I'm asking this in the context of a SE media dropping scenario, where a file when executed, sends data to an internal server, to register that the file has been executed.